# Arch Linux with Mate ignores exports in ~/.bash_profile and ~/.profile

Tags: arch-linux, environment-variables, mate-desktop

I use Arch Linux and need to add environment variables on login. I have Plasma, Cinnamon and Mate installed. For some reason the environment variables in ~/.profile and ~/.bash_profile are not set when I use Mate, it works with Plasma and Cinnamon though. I've also tried different login managers (SDDM, LightDM, GDM3) with no success. The strange thing is that the files are definitely parsed by Mate, because I launch an application (quicktile) after the exports. Removing the application doesn't change anything either. If I manually source ~/.profile after login it works.

~/.bash_profile

```
#
# ~/.bash_profile
#
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
[[ -f ~/.profile ]] && . ~/.profile
```

~/.profile

```
export PATH="$HOME/SDI/ct-ng/bin:$HOME/SDI/x-tools/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
quicktile --daemonize &
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

**Update for clarification:**

Expected behavior (which does happen when I log in to Plasma or Cinnamon):

I open the terminal and execute a binary that is located within one of the paths that I export in ~/.profile.

Experienced behavior when I log in to Mate:

I open the terminal but it cannot find the binary. I have to manually source ~/.profile before I can use it. This leads to quicktile being loaded again and throwing errors because of that, which is how I noticed that the file must have been parsed before.